# what is "file_like_object", what is "file"; pickle.load() and pickle.loads()

Tags: python, pickle, data-processing

I am figuring out the differences between the `pickle.load()` and `pickle.loads()`. Somebody said what kind of object that `pickle.load()` process is "file_like_object",  however, `pickle.loads()` corresponds to "file object".

Comment: All of the information you seek is readily accessible from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivially available from the documentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your choice of which function to use depends on the object from whence you are loading the pickled data:

---

[`pickle.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) is used to load pickled data from a `bytes` string. The "s" in `loads` refers to the fact that in Python 2, the data was loaded from a *string*.

For example:

```
import pickle

with open("myobj.pickle", "rb") as f:
    rawdata = f.read()

myobj = pickle.loads(rawdata)
```

---

[`pickle.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) is used to load pickled data from a *file-like object*. This is any object that acts like a file - in this case, meaning it has a `read()` method that returns `bytes`.

For example:

```
import pickle

with open("myobj.pickle", "rb") as f:
    myobj = pickle.load(f)
```

---

This same convention applies to the `dump`/`dumps` functions in the pickle library, as well as the `json` module and others.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with how we dump the object? I mean, we don't have to use .load() only on an object that is .dump() and we can use .load() on an object that is .dumps() too? There is no one-on-one mapping on using .dump()/.load() and .dumps()/.loads() and what only matters is the type of the file to load, byte string or file-like. Am I right?