# redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'dict'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, redis, byte

Goal: store a `dict()` or `{}` as the value for a key-value pair, to `set()` onto **Redis**.

Code

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis()

value = 180

my_dict = dict(bar=value)

r.set('foo', my_dict)
```

```
redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'dict'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot pass a dictionary object as a value in the `set()` operation to Redis.

However, we can use either `pickle` or `json` to get the `Bytes` of an object.

Whichever you already have imported would be optimal, imho.

---

**Pickle**

Serialize to pickle (with [`pickle.dumps`](https://pythontic.com/modules/pickle/dumps)) pre-`set()`

```
import pickle

my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

dict_bytes = pickle.dumps(my_dict)

r.set('my_key', dict_bytes)
```

Deserialize the object (dict) (with [`pickle.loads`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498929/what-is-file-like-object-what-is-file-pickle-load-and-pickle-loads)) post-`get()`:

```
dict_bytes = r.get('my_key')

my_dict = pickle.loads(dict_bytes)
```

---

**JSON string**

Serialize to JSON string (with [`json.dumps`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-dumps-in-python/)) pre-`set()`

```
import json

my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

dict_str = json.dumps(my_dict)

r.set('my_key', dict_str)
```

Deserialize the object (dict) (with [`json.loads`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-loads-in-python/)) post-`get()`:

```
dict_str = r.get('my_key')

my_dict = json.loads(dict_str)
```